# How to obtain the Least-significant bits of a number

Tags: .net, vb.net, hex

I wonder if it's possible to obtain the Least-significant bits of a number.

Example :

```
 uint intValue = Int32.MaxValue;
 uint LSB = intValue & 0x0000FFFF;
```

from :

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-cookbook/0596003390/ch01s06.html

but I need this in VB.net.

I tried :

```
 Dim intValue As UInteger = 39101
 Dim LSB As UInteger = intValue And &HFFFF
```

Any idea?

Comment: `Dim sum As Integer = 19774 + Convert.ToInt32("0x000000FF", 16)`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/how-to-convert-hexadecimal-strings-to-numbers

Comment: @VisualVincent If you look at when i commented and what the post looked like before he did major editing,including title changes etc. you will understand why me and daniel hydeman answered what we did. Just so you know the title when i commented was "VB.NET : how to add an Hexa value to an integer" .

Comment: @Julien : What your code does is correct. The unsigned low word of 39101 _is_ 39101. One `UInteger` is equal to two `UShort`s. The maximum value of a `UShort` is 65535, so 39101 will fit in the first `UShort` without a problem. What is it that you are actually trying to achieve? It would be great if you could show us some example output.

Comment: @K.Madden : Ah, you're right. Sorry about that. I didn't consider looking at the revision history. When I entered the question it was asked an hour ago and only edited 35 minutes ago so I didn't think it would've undergone such a major change in that little time. My apologies.

Comment: @VisualVincent no problem at all!

Comment: See the [BitVector32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.-ctor) class (similar to a `BitArray`). Pass it an Integer, then take the bits you want.

Comment: You can tell it that the &FFFF is an unsigned integer by suffixing it with "UI" thus: `&FFFFUI`.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you visualize what is going on.  It shows various masks.  Look at 'bits' at every Stop.

```
    Dim bits As String
    Dim intValue As UInteger = 39101
    Dim LSB As UInteger
    bits = Convert.ToString(intValue, 2).PadLeft(32, "0"c)
    Stop
    LSB = intValue And &HFFFFUI 'keep 16 bits
    bits = Convert.ToString(LSB, 2).PadLeft(32, "0"c)
    Stop
    LSB = intValue And &HFFUI 'keep 8 bits
    bits = Convert.ToString(LSB, 2).PadLeft(32, "0"c)
    Stop
    LSB = intValue And &HFUI 'keep 4 bits
    bits = Convert.ToString(LSB, 2).PadLeft(32, "0"c)
```